# extension of CRT from $k$ primes to $n$ primes

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $1 \leq k \leq n$ be integers and let $p_1 <\dots< p_n$ be $n$ distinct primes.

We denote $N=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i$ and $K=\prod\limits_{i=1}^kp_i$.

We Consider the mapping $E:\mathbb{Z}_K\to \mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times\cdots \mathbb{Z}_{p_n}$ defined by:
$$E(m)=(m \ \text{mod} \ p_1,\dots,m \ \text{mod}\  p_n)$$

Let $m_1\neq m_2$ be two distinct members of $\mathbb{Z}_K$ and define: 
$$\forall\ i\in[n] : b_i = \begin{cases} 
      1 & \text{if}:\ E(m_1)_i\neq E(m_2)_i \\
      0 & \text{if}:\ E(m_1)_i=E(m_2)_i \\
   \end{cases}
$$
Prove that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i}>N/K$.

**Important Note:** As I talk about the domain $\mathbb{Z}_K$ I talk about the set of numbers $S=\{0,1,2,\dots,K-1\}$ not about the group $(\mathbb{Z}_K,+_{K})$ so actually $E$ is well defined and it can be thought of as a set of $K$ pairs.

**Another Important Note:** This mapping is the basis for a family of error correcting codes called CRT codes. But, this question is about number theory and not about cs.

Comment: Your $E$ does not seem to be well-defined.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Why so, sir? You can observe that we map each $m\in\mathbb{Z}_K$ to a unique vector in $\prod\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$.

Comment: No, you are really not. For example your setup would allow $K=2$ and $p_2=3$. But a number is not determined mod $3$ given what it is mod $2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft no since if $p_2=3$ then $K=6$.

Comment: No, you allowed $k <n$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You are confused between $k$ and $K$

Comment: No, I have read what you wrote carefully. Maybe you should read it again. The case I gave was with $k=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: But why it makes the mapping not well defined. Every value is sent to another value. We don’t have a value that is mapped to two separate values.@TobiasKildetoft

Comment: The map is not well defined because you define it on representatives of the congruense classes in a way that is not independent of the choice of representative.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft But I do not deal with the congruence classes I just consider the set $Z_K$ as a set not as a field

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is it okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $m_1 < m_2$ and consider the product 
$$
   (m_2 - m_1) \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i}.
$$
Then for each $i$ with $1 \le i \le n$, $p_i$ divides this product, because one of two cases must hold:

- Either $p_i \mid m_2 - m_1$, in which case it appears in the first factor,
- Or $m_1 \not\equiv m_2 \pmod {p_i}$, in which case $b_i = 1$ and $p_i$ appears in the second factor.

Since all $n$ primes divide this product, so does their product $N$:

$$N \mid (m_2 - m_1) \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i}.$$

In particular, we have the inequality
$$
   (m_2 - m_1) \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i} \ge N \implies \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{b_i} \ge \frac{N}{m_2 - m_1}
$$
and this implies the inequality you want, because $\frac{N}{m_2-m_1} > \frac N K$.